# 3 divides coefficents of this $q$-series

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, partitions

Denote $\phi(q):=\prod_{j\geq1}(1-q^j)$ and let $\xi=e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}$ be a cube root of unity.

Define the sequence $u(n)$ by
$$\prod_{n\geq1}\prod_{s=1}^2(1-q^n\xi^{ns})(1-q^{2n}\xi^{ns})
=\sum_{n\geq0}u(n)\,q^n.$$

> **QUESTION.** Is this true?
> $$\sum_{n\geq0} u(3n+2)q^{3n+2}=3q^2\,\phi^2(q^9)\,\phi^2(q^{18}).$$

**Addendum.** To help readers, if we let
$$f_n(q)=(1 + q^{3n - 1} + q^{2(3n - 1)})(1 + q^{3n - 2} + q^{2(3n-2)})
(1 - q^{3n})^2,$$
then we have
$$\prod_{n\geq1}\prod_{s=1}^2(1-q^n\xi^{ns})(1-q^{2n}\xi^{ns})
=\prod_{n\geq1}f_n(q) f_n(q^2).$$

Answer (score 6):

Trivially
$$
\prod_{n\geq1} f_n(q)=\frac{\left(q^3;q^3\right)^4_{\infty }}{(q;q)_{\infty } \left(q^9;q^9\right){}_{\infty }}.
$$
Denoting $A(q)=(q;q)_{\infty }(q^2;q^2)_{\infty }$, one can see that in order to prove OP's claim it is enough to perform trisection of $A(q)$, which can be found in Michael Somos' article [A Multisection of q-Series](https://grail.eecs.csuohio.edu/%7Esomos/multiq.html) . Using formulas from section 4 of this article, by simple algebra one can find
$$
A(q \xi)\xi^2+{A\left({q}{\xi}^2\right)}{\xi}=-A(q)-3qA(q^9).
$$
This reduces OP's claim to verification of an eta-product identity:
$$
A\left(q^3\right)^4-\left(3 q A\left(q^9\right)+A(q)\right) A\left(q^9\right) A(q)^2-9 q^2 A\left(q^9\right)^3 A(q)=0.
$$
For this purpose, one can consult Somos' [table](https://web.archive.org/web/20190709150645/https://eta.math.georgetown.edu/index.html) of such identities. With high probability it can be found there. Even if it can not be found, identities for eta-products can be verified automatically using modular machine.

Thus the identity is related to Ramanujan's famous cubic continued fraction, in other words very classical, textbook stuff.

Comment: The eta-product identity you state is $\texttt{q18_8_36a}$. It is equivalent to Berndt, Part IV, p. 186, Entry 34 (i) Eq. (34.1).